# Delete everything before and after a string using sed

Tags: awk, sed

I have data in a file in below form :--

```
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "QUERY" to continue.

SQL> _id                              : MS
itm                         : 4
it                          : NO

------

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I want to delete everything before _id and after ------ .

To delete everything before _id I used following sed

```
sed '/_id/,$!d' 1.txt
```

It deletes the row before _id but doesnt delete  SQL>  .

Similarly I used below sed to delete all everything after ------ but it doesnt delete the rows below it

```
sed 's/\------.*/------/' 1.txt
```

Can someone help me where I am doing wrong ? What I need is :--

```
_id                         : MS
itm                         : 4
it                          : NO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using sed

Try:

```
$ sed -n '/_id/,/------/{ s/.*_id/_id/; /------/q; p}' 1.txt
_id                              : MS
itm                         : 4
it                          : NO
```

**How it works:**

- `-n`

  This tells sed not to print unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `/_id/,/------/{...}`

  This selects a range of lines that start with a line containing `_id` and end with a line containing `------`.  For those lines the commands in curly braces are executed.
- `s/.*_id/_id/`

  On the line that contains `_id`, this removes everything before `_id`.
- `/------/q`

  On the line that contains `------`, this tells sed to quit.
- `p`

  For lines that reach this command, this tells sed to print the line.

### Using awk

```
$ awk -v RS='------' '/_id/{sub(/.*_id/, "_id"); print}' ORS="" 1.txt
_id                              : MS
itm                         : 4
it                          : NO
```

**How it works:**

- `-v RS='------'`

  This set `------` as the *record separator*.
- `/_id/{sub(/.*_id/, "_id"); print}`

  For any records that contain `_id`, we remove everything before `_id` and print the current record.
- `ORS=""`

  This sets the output record separator to the empty string.

Comment: I have one more question. Suppose data is  "it  : NO ------ " in that case it doesnt even print line .

Comment: Actually found a way around . Please ignore it.Thank you